# Can I write a trigger in MySQL to take effect both in AFTER DELETE and AFTER UPDATE?

Tags: mysql, triggers

Just like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `adu_order` AFTER DELETE UPDATE ON `order`
```

But it's not ok. And I got an error prompt when trying to create it.

Then is it possible to achieve such a goal?

Comment: This syntax is currently not supported. One option is to try to encapsulate your logic in a stored procedure and invoke from every trigger (`AFTER DELETE` and `AFTER UPDATE`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not specify two events at once. " AFTER DELETE UPDATE" is not supported. You have to pass one.  See the manual for trigger. Hope it works for you.

```
 CREATE TRIGGER  trigger_name
    [BEFORE|AFTER] [INSERT|UPDATE|DELETE] ON table_name
    FOR EACH ROW [FOLLOWS|PRECEDES] existing_trigger_name
    BEGIN
    …
    END
```